# python pandas | conditional aggregation- revised question

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

| volume | price | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 3 | 2021-09-29 04:00:00-04:00 |
| 300 | 2 | 2021-09-29 04:30:00-04:00 |
| 700 | 5 | 2021-09-29 05:30:00-04:00 |
| 500 | 9 | 2021-09-29 06:00:00-04:00 |
| 900 | 22 | 2021-09-29 06:30:00-04:00 |
| 400 | 29 | 2021-09-29 07:00:00-04:00 |

posted this questionbefore,  but got an error  may be because i omitted some detail. This is a revised one

be noted that datatype for datetime is    datetime64[ns, America/New_York]. and the dataframe i stored in a variable "df"

Can you help me with the  below aggregation?

Add the volume before 2021-09-29 06:15:00  and after 2021-09-29 04:15:00 (expected result should be 1500)

Add the volume if price is greater than 20. (Expected result  is 1300)

Comment: If your column `datetime` is in a `datetime` format, you can try `df[df['datetime'].between('2021-09-29 04:15:00','2021-09-29 06:15:00')].volume.sum()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your column `datetime` isn't already in datetime format run the following line:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
```

Then if you want to store start and ending dates/time as variables (as requested in the comment below), you can make them strings and concatenate them before passing them to the `.between` function, then sum the volume column:

```
target_date = '2021-09-29'
target_from = '04:15:00'
target_to = '06:15:00'
start_datetime = f"{target_date} {target_from}"
end_datetime = f"{target_date} {target_to}"
df[df['datetime'].between(start_datetime, end_datetime)].volume.sum()
```

Output:

```
1500
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Derek.  instead of changing the data and time directly in the "between" clause. i' d like make a variable, such as target_date = 2021-09-29,  target_from = 04:15:00, target_to = 06:15:00.  can you advise on how i should modify  the function given by above

Comment: If those new variables are strings, you can concatenate them together: `start_datetime = f"{target_date} {target_from}"; end_datetime = f"{target_date} {target_to}"` and then pass these to the .between function